# django supplying login credentials in any view url

Tags: django, authentication, pingdom

Is there any way in django to perform login using credentials supplied while accessing any view in the application?

My motivation here is availability monitoring using a service such as [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/). Most of the urls I want to validated their availability are decorated with a `@login_required` which makes it impossible to access unless I have previously logged in.

My idea solution will be a way to access my views while supplying credentials in GET or POST parameters. Another alternative could probably be a site uptime monitoring service that supports logging in and acquiring a session prior to accessing the URL in question.

### Update

Thanks to @Filip Dupanović's direction and the code from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) my simple working middleware looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

class AuthenticationEverywhereMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware to allow logging in by supplying login credentials in any URL
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        if (request.GET.get('authenticateEverywhere','') == 'GET'):
            username = request.GET['username']
            password = request.GET['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
```

I have added the triggering parameter `authenticateEverywhere` to prevent any possible clashes with views that might use `username` or `password` parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most certainly can! You'll need to write a custom [middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs) that implements a custom `process_request` method where you'll be able to inspect the request object, obtain the credentials and sign the user in before the request gets routed to a view that's decorated with `login_required`.